# Can we use step in GDB without breakpoints?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, gdb

First, thank you for all the helps so far.

In Visual Studio, we can do Debug -> Step In without setting any breakpoints. In GDB, it seems like we HAVE to use breakpoints.

```
int main ()
{
   int a = 10;
   int b = 111;
   return 0;
}
```

My goal is to find the addresses of each variable (say int a, int b). I want to know the values before and after the assignment of a and b.

If we compile and run gdb on this source code, the program will terminate, and we don't have a way to trace the stack.

So is there a way to step one single statement at a time in GDB like we do in VS?

Thanks.
(no breakpoint, cannot use cout....no watchers..)

Comment: Bad example code. An optimizing compiler could either put a and b into a register or even optimize them out altogether.

Comment: @TurboJ  Thanks for pointing this out. Yes, however, that's the goal of this challenge, and this is the way professor wanted to show him in class ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can step in with **step** (s) command. First you **start** the program (as opposed to using **run**), so it would stop at the beginning.

Comment: Glad I could help. So, you're being __taught__ programming with open source tools? I'm glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put a breakpoint in main and then step line by line using `next`.  VS does that implicitly.

Comment: Thank you :) Yeah VS does that implicitly.